# How to execute code in PHP

Tags: php

Excuse me if my question is simple.Please see the following code. I know what's happening.

```
    <?php

    session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $login = $_POST['login'];}

    else {echo "Connection Error";}

    if(checking the fields is correct) {

    //check it in database and if there is, assign the client session to the $_SESSION['username']

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    //Login success 

}
```

Consider we have the code above. If a hacker does not use the `POST` method and if he uses the `GET` method, as the result he should get the `echo "Connection Error";` message.

Now my question is: If the hacker uses the `GET` method instead the `POST` method and also he can inter the username and password values correctly, can he do log in action successfully?

Comment: Ideally there should be a termination after "Connection Error" or it should be the last condition check, means all your checking and login success should be inside if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST").

Comment: I agree with @codeSun but in the case above the $_POST array stays empty, so the database validation will surely fail, thus the nothing gets logged in the $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['login']` are available only when user sends POST request.

I recommend rewriting your code like this:

```php
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $login = $_POST['login'];

    if (checking_the_fields_is_correct($username, $login)) {

        //check it in database and if there is, assign the client session to the $_SESSION['username']

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        //Login success
    }

} else {

    exit("Bad request");

}
```

But if you really think about security, I recommend you look at frameworks (Symfony, Laravel) which have their own mature authorization 'modules'.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about security, you should never implement authentification by yourself. There are a lot of attack types, that may be much more complicated, then you can resist.
Use any of authentification system (or web-framework), and that will save you from a lot of problems!